# ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, can i share a .py file with a package included

Tags: python, package

I'm trying to share a `.py` file with someone. Is there a way to send a `.py` file with a package already included, or will they have to install it themselves?

Trying to send a file with the `tkinter` package, but when they open it, they just get this error.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You might use pyinstaller to generate an executable file or a folder with all required script/files in it.
You can find out more about [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) here.
You find the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html) here.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a way to repo my code from Github and it work without them having to install any modules? or is that possible